# Python socket recv from java client

Tags: java, python, sockets, socketserver

I have a problem with a simple python tcp server *(I'm using `SocketServer` class)* that have to receive data from a java client.

Here the server side code:

```
class ServerRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    [...]
    def handle(self):
        requestCode = struct.unpack('>i', self.request.recv(4))[0]
        [...]
    [...]
```

Here there is the client:

```
addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
clientSocket = new Socket();
clientSocket.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
clientSocketDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
int   requestCode = 1;
clientSocketDataOutputStream.writeInt(requestCode);
clientSocketDataOutputStream.flush();
```

I start the Python server and then I try to execute the client that have to send an integer to the server.

On the server side Python raise an exception because the `recv(4)` function does not read 4 bytes, it returns only one byte.

My java client sends 4 bytes correctly in fact, if I try to call `recv(1)` 4 times it reads 4 bytes correctly.

I tried to write a Python client that execute the same operation of my java client and in this case the server's `recv(4)` works well.

How to solve this problem? I thought to implement a simple python `buffered reader function` that reads from socket byte by byte but I'm sure that a smarter solution exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the recv doesn't have to read 4 bytes, it just grabs whatever is there up to a max of four bytes.  Since, as you said, you can call recv(1) 4 times.  you can do this

```
def recvall(sock, size):
    msg = ''
    while len(msg) < size:
        part = sock.recv(size-len(msg))
        if part == '': 
            break # the connection is closed
        msg += part
    return msg
```

this will repeatedly call `recv` on `sock` until `size` bytes are received. if `part == ''` the socket is closed so it will return whatever was there before the close

so change

```
requestCode = struct.unpack('>i', self.request.recv(4))[0]
```

to

```
requestCode = struct.unpack('>i', recvall(self.request, 4))[0]
```

I'd suggest making `recvall` a method of your class to make things cleaner.

---

this is a modification of a method from the safe socket class defined here: http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html

Answer (score 0):

recv(4) will read a *maximum* of 4 bytes. See the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html . I think making a simple buffered reader function is a perfectly acceptable solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something from [io](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/io.html) module? [BufferedRWPair](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/io.html#io.BufferedRWPair) for example.